# Ansible add keys

Tags: list, loops, ssh, ansible

I am trying add some keys to my root authorized_keys on the instance, but looks like it is overwriting the list and only stick the last key, 
Any one know how to sort this ?

```
- name: Set authorized key
  authorized_key:
    user: root
    state: present
    key: "{{item}}"
  loop: "{{keys}}"
```

the vars file is

```
keys:
    - "https://gitlab.com/user1.keys"
    - "https://github.com/user2.keys"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"Looks like it is overwriting the list and only stick the last key, Anyone know how to sort this ?"*

A: By default [authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html#get-url-downloads-files-from-http-https-or-ftp-to-node) does not remove non-specified keys from the authorized_keys file. See parameter [exclusive](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html#parameters). Make sure what data you feed *`key`* with.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, under the [`exclusive` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html):

> Whether to remove all other non-specified keys from the
>   authorized_keys file. Multiple keys can be specified in a single key
>   string value by separating them by newlines. This option is not loop
>   aware, so if you use with_ , it will be exclusive per iteration of the
>   loop. If you want multiple keys in the file you need to pass them all
>   to key in a single batch as mentioned above.

This means that you can achieve what you want by using a Jinja [`join` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) on your array:

```
- name: Set authorized key
  authorized_key:
    user: root
    state: present
    key: "{{ keys | join('\n') }}"
```

Comment: I try to run it but it shows errors like. ```fatal: [test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error getting key from: https://gitlab.com/name1.keys\nhttps://github.com/name2.keys"}```